# Camera Intent picture file path

Tags: android, path, image

I'm trying to get the path of the pictures that i take with the camera as a String. When i try to take the pictures with my code then the String is empty. When i close my app, open the camera app and take a picture there, then re-open my app and use my code then i get the String of the last photo that i took with the camera app. My question is why does my Camera Intent not work and why does it work when i use the camera app?

Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {     
      case R.id.btnImageCapture:
        Intent openCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(openCamera, OPEN_CAMERA); 
                    break;
    }
}
```

---

```
private String getLastImagePath() {
            final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
            Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
                    null, null, imageOrderBy);
            if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                imageCursor.close();
                return fullPath;
            }
        }
```

---

```
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         switch(requestCode){
         case OPEN_CAMERA:
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                 String picturePath = getLastImagePath(); 
                 break;
             } 
             }
        }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the Uri of the image that's given to you in onActivityResult? data.getData();

Comment: It's because i need the file path. ;)

Comment: Try out my answer using the Uri.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Uri is populated. How can i check it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It works..

```
  private Uri imageUri;

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {     
      case R.id.btnImageCapture:

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_CAMERA);
                    break;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case OPEN_CAMERA:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely need the file path, because I must save it in an SQLite db.

Comment: It needs to be jpg? can´t be png?